# Can The HTML for the Pay Link Be Updated?

Tags: paypal

Looking at the "Pay Link or Button" option from PayPal.com/buttons,  the following code is generated once you fill in your options (except, of course, your client id and button id is provided):

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&components=hosted-buttons&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD"></script>
<div id="paypal-container-BUTTON_ID"></div>
<script>
  paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "BUTTON_ID",
  }).render("#paypal-container-BUTTON_ID")
</script>
```

Is it possible to utilize this with some additional HTML so the buttons aren't so big compared to the given text under the product name? Maybe additional parameters to go with the paypal.HostedButtons and I just can't find where they are? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the buttons being too wide (by default they seem to fill the container up to 750px wide), that's straightforward, just add a max-width parameter. e.g.

```
<div id="paypal-container-BUTTON_ID" style="max-width:400px;"></div>
```

It's also possible to add a `<style>` tag above that button code that uses CSS to modify the HTML that is added by that button JS, if you need to make more bespoke modifications such as changing layout, text appearance, and the like.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for that. Modifying the text would be nice too. How would adding the style tag work?

Comment: You put CSS selectors in it that modify what you want to modify about the rendered HTML

Comment: Outside of the first set of script tags or the 2nd set? Also, how would I identify what the elements are so that I can change them?

Comment: The style tag will work anywhere and technically should be in <head> but just put it above the button code you have.  To see the rendered HTML right click and inspect

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and go from there.

Comment: I tried a little experimenting and no success so far. Clearly I need to learn a lot more. I see #paypal-form-fields-container-BUTTON_ID #price-label { font-size: 28px; }. I can't figure out what to do with it though.

Comment: Well in your `<style>` tag do `#paypal-form-fields-container-BUTTON_ID #price-label { font-size: 50px !important; transform: rotate(180deg); } ` or, you know, whatever it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: <style>
 #paypal-form-fields-container-9ZW2SR2N72QNL #price-label {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
  </style>

Comment: This didn't have any effect.

Comment: Cascading Style Sheets...cascade. Since it's specified later as 28px, you need `!important` if you want to override the later setting.

Comment: That still didn't work. I used font-size: 12px !important;

Comment: There it goes! I had some stuff that was allegedly commented from copying and pasting and I thought to myself, I wonder if this isn't actually working. So I removed it. Bam! Thank you!

Comment: Good to know I was looking at it right initially. 